# Separación en columnas R

Tags: r

Quiero separar texto en columnas como lo hace excel pero en R, tengo el siguiente código:

```
df <- within(data=Libro1, B <-data.frame
                     (do.call('rbind',strsplit(B,";",fixed=TRUE))))
```

la base de datos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el código me genera esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver me esta duplicando información, yo quiero que genere una base como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de los datos:

```
Libro1 <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,4,3,8,8,7),
                     B=c('1;2;3;4', '2;9', '1', '2', '4;3;9', '4;5;6;7;8;9', '7'),
                     C=c(13, 14, 14, 10, 13, 12, 12),
                     D=c(13, 15, 11, 6, 14, 17, 18),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Agradezco por favor su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que `rbind` esta reciclando valores para completar el total de las nuevas columnas. Este método es útil cuando el "split" genera siempre la misma cantidad de columnas, como en este casos son variables, esto nos sirve. Una forma con R base podría ser:

```
lista <- strsplit(libro1$B,";",fixed=TRUE)
m <- max(sapply(lista, length))
do.call(rbind, lapply(lista, function(x) {c(x,rep(NA,m))[1:m]}))

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  NA   NA  
[2,] "2"  "9"  NA   NA   NA   NA  
[3,] "1"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[4,] "2"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[5,] "4"  "3"  "9"  NA   NA   NA  
[6,] "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" 
[7,] "7"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Básicamente lo que se hace es completar con `NA` a la derecha hasta completar la cantidad máxima de columnas que se van generar.

Otra forma posible, sería usando `stingr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(libro1$B, ";", n=Inf)
```

O bien con `tidyverse`, siempre que sepas de antemano cual es máximo de columnas, se puede resolver todo en un lote muy compacto de código:

```
library(tidyverse)
Libro1 %>%
    separate(B,paste0("B",1:6),sep=';')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente.